# What is the word/philosophy to describe someone who is in charge of their own destiny?

Tags: single-word-requests

Perhaps opposite of fatalistic. My English Teacher is giving a prize to whoever can get this word next week and everything I found on google is not the answer!

Comment: Philosophy of Karma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma

Comment: The question itself is too vague. Does it mean each person is *responsible* for their own *actions*? That each person *determines* their own *fate* (that there is no such thing as chance)? What does *in* ***charge*** *of their own* ***destiny*** mean?

Comment: Yeah, it is a vague question isn't it? If it helps, a classic example of what I am talking about is the Shakespeare quote, "Men are at some times masters of their own fate." That kind of quality, someone who is not just responsible for their own actions, but more willing to fight against the world itself to get what you want, EG even if you weren't born in the position of a monarch, you still hold a rebellion etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

The term you need is

***indeterminism***

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/indeterminism) :

(ethics, religion, uncountable) 
The doctrine that all human actions are not so much determined by the preceding events, conditions, causes or karma as by deliberate choice or free will.

***[indeterminist](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/indeterminist)***

One who believes the doctrine of indeterminism.

Comment: Indeterminism means the doctrine that not all events are wholly determined by antecedent causes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the word **Karma** as defined by Oxford dictionary.

(in Hinduism and Buddhism) the sum of a person's actions in this and previous states of existence, viewed as deciding their fate in future existences.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/karma